# Agregar un objeto a un ArrayList Java

Tags: java

Tengo una clase que se llama "Articulo" y en el main estoy haciendo que el usuario pueda agregar articulos desde teclado en la consola. La idea de esta segunda clase llamada "Tienda" es almacenar estos articulos. Pero siempre que pongo en el main que me printee la lista siempre sale el array vacio.

```
public class Tienda {

Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<Object> Lista = new ArrayList<>();
public static String nombre = "Tiendita";

public Tienda(String nombre) {
    System.out.println(nombre);
}

public Tienda() {

}

public void agregarALaLista(Articulo a) {
    Lista.add(new Articulo());
 }
 public void buscaArticulo (String codigo){
 }

public void vende(String codigo, int num) {

}

public void escribePedido(int min) {}
```

y estoy llamando a la la lista de la siguiente manera:

```
System.out.println(tienda.Lista);
```

Comment: creo que debe ir asi  , static  ArrayList<Object> Lista = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: me sigue saliendo [] sin nada adentro.

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo, que la lista que necesitas gestionar, es una lista de Artículos. Si es así, teniendo una clase Artículo, la lista la podrías declarar como sigue:

```
ArrayList<Articulo> Lista = new ArrayList<Articulo>();
```

En primer lugar, normalmente, se utiliza el constructor para dar valores iniciales a las variables definidas por la clase. En tu clase tienda, las variables sn, Lista y el nombre, deberías inicializarlas en el constructor.

```
    public class Tienda {    
        Scanner sn;
        ArrayList<Articulo> Lista;
        public String nombre;
   
    public Tienda() {
        sn = new Scanner(System.in);
        Lista = new ArrayList<Articulo>();
        nombre = "Tiendita";
   ....
```

Suponiendo una clase Artículo como sigue:

```
public class Articulo{
    float precio;
    String nombre;
    
    public Articulo() {         
    }
    
    public void setPrecio(float p) {
        precio = p;
    }
    public void setNombre(String n) {
        nombre = n;
    }
    
     @Override
      public String toString() {
        return nombre + ":" + precio;
      }
    
}
```

Si te fijas, sobreescribo el metodo toString, para que puedas hacer el print de la lista directamente, si no, mostrará la referencia de cada objeto.

Y, finalmente, utilizando tu clase tienda cambiando el ArrayList tal y como te indiqué al principio y utilizando la clase Artículo comentada, sería:

```
Tienda t1 = new Tienda();
Articulo a1 = new Articulo();
    a1.setNombre("Test");
    a1.setPrecio(1);
t1.agregarALaLista(a1);
System.out.println(t1.Lista);
```